# Using angular material components datepicker and autocomplete distort screen when used multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

I have a working app but when using multiple components of **md-datepicker** and **md-autocomplete** directives when clicked the browse tries to embed dynamically created content and shows some kind of distortion. I tough this was a bug but I should raise it here first.

does any one know about it ?
here is the screenshot for the two sates  of my app before clicking **md-autocomplete** and after clicking the last auto complete that says **Guide or staff name**

This is the second time I faced this thing, before the datepicker was the issue but used other datepicker from angular ui.

but now when I use autocomplete it just repeated that issue.

thanks

1. [image]
2. [image]

Comment: Can you provide the fiddle/ plunkr link or any example with detail

Comment: can post the code here but seems like this is container and dynamic dom fighting for space so code will be value less